# Adding recyclerview inside Fragment crops recycler view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have a recyclerview, which contains a `viewPager`, and `viewPager` contains  a `recyclerview`

The issue is tat `recyclerView` inside `viewpager` is cropping items.

There are 15 items, and it shows 12.5 items, other items gets cropped.

I made it work by setting a random `3000dp` height of `viewpager view` and it started showing all items, with much additional space on bottom, and this is not the solution, i added this just to check where the problem exists.

**ParentRecyclerView**

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.stats_tab_layout, parent, false)
    return StatsViewHolder(view,context, mDataList)          
}

class StatsViewHolder (view: View, context: Context, dataList: List<PlayerProfileModel>?) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

    val tabLayout= view.tab_playerStats
    val viewPager= view.viewPager_playerStats


    init {
        setupViewPager()
    }


    private fun setupViewPager() {        
        //Created 2 fragments and added them in adapter
    }
}
```

**View Pager XML**

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_playerStats"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/PlayerTabTextAppearance"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewPager_playerStats"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView54"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/view5"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.64"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
    app:tabContentStart="8dp"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/black"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/white" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view5" />
```

There is a recycler view inside fragment, I set its width & height to `match_parent`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: where is `@+id/view5`?

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman : view5 is header over the recyclerview